# Download document on the same page when using antd upload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using [antd's upload component](https://ant.design/components/upload/) to allow a user to upload a document. Now after the user has uploaded it, I also want to allow him to download the attachment just uploaded. I know the documentation explains this to do in the following way:

```
import { Upload, Button, Icon } from 'antd';

const props = {
    action: '//jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/',
    onChange({ file, fileList }) {
        if (file.status !== 'uploading') {
        console.log(file, fileList);
        }
    },
    defaultFileList: [{
        uid: '1',
        name: 'xxx.png',
        status: 'done',
        response: 'Server Error 500', // custom error message to show
        url: 'http://www.baidu.com/xxx.png',
    }],
    };

ReactDOM.render(
    <Upload {...props}>
        <Button>
        <Icon type="upload" /> Upload
        </Button>
    </Upload>,
    mountNode
);
```

But I want to allow the download on the same page and don't want to open a new window on click. How could I do this? Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: where is your code ?

Answer (score 0):

The [default behavior](https://github.com/Trufinol/ant-design/blob/master/components/upload/UploadList.tsx) is to open the file in a new window.

You can override this behavior by providing an `onPreview` prop for `Upload`:

> `onPreview`: A callback function, will be executed when file link or preview icon is clicked.

```
 <Upload
      //...
      onPreview={handlePreview}
    >
```

Now write your own logic to download the file in `handlePreview`. You can find many examples online on how to achieve that.

```
const handlePreview = (file) => {
    console.log(file);
    // write how you want to download
}
```